# long feature vector size in Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to design a Neural Network where I want the feature vector size equal to the input vector size. In essence, I have an image ( my input ) and I wish to perform a regression task on 
*each* of the pixels (i.e., my output is a prediction on how I should act on each of the pixel).

However, my experience with ML ( newbie ) seems to show that the size of the output vector is usually small compared to the input vector size. Is there a reason why I must design my network in a similar manner ? Are there any pitfalls in having an output feature vector as long as the input vector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely have the output of the network as big as the input. Look for example at [UNet](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-semantic-segmentation-with-unet-6be4f42d4b47) for semantic segmentation. In that case there is one output for each pixel which represents the category (class) of that pixel.